# Bards magical Journey clicking

Tags: league-of-legends

I know already that I have to click on the tunnel created and not on the entrence to enter the Journey, but my question is, if I click on the tunnel, will my champion automaticly walk to the entrence and enter the journey ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if the journey does not disappear in the meantime you'll keep walking towards it.

Comment: simple question simple answer. Thx!